# Is it necessary to show Google analytics privacy policy in IOS application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

1. In my IOS application i am using google analytics, is it necessary to tell the app users that we using google analytics.
2. Is it necessary to show the google analytics primary policy in App.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)**

> 3.12 Apps should have all included URLs fully functional when you submit it for review, such as support and privacy policy URLs

In section 3.12: It specify that when you submit your application than you must have to include privacy policy URL. That does not mean that you need to show a separate page in application to show privacy policies.

*Personally as a mobile user I have never seen privacy policy page of any analytics in application so far.*

Also from **[Google Analytics Protocol SDK Policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy)** you have to take care of following points.

## Measurement Protocol / SDK / User ID Policy

All applications using the Measurement Protocol / SDKs / User ID must adhere to the following policies:

- You must make sure you have the full rights to use this service, to upload data, and to use it with your Google Analytics account.
- You will give your end users proper notice about the implementations and features of Google Analytics you use (e.g. notice about what data you will collect via Google Analytics, and whether this data can be connected to other data you have about the end user). You will either get consent from your end users, or provide them with the opportunity to opt-out from the implementations and features you use.
- If you use an SDK to implement any Google Analytics Advertising Features, such as Audience Reporting or Remarketing, you will abide by the [Policy for Google Analytics Advertising Features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2700409), in addition to the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), or any other applicable policy.
- You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as certain names, Social Security Numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form.
- If you upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual, your Google Analytics account can be terminated, and you may lose your Google Analytics data.